# Why Radar widget is not working in Mavic_2?

Tags: dji-sdk

DJI MSDK:4.8.1

platform:Android

Radar widget is not working properly in Mavic_2 where as it works fine in other drones (Mavic_pro,Mavic_air). Is there anything we need to handle so that it works fine in Mavic_2?

Comment: I faced the same issue with the UX SDK sample from the github. Is there any precondition to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start the UAV obstacle avoidance system in the official application such as DJI Pilot, which can solve your problem at once.